# Calculate percentile from set of numbers

Tags: javascript

For example if I have array of numbers like `3,5,8,1,2,3` and my input `1` ,  I want to calculate percentage of times  the number is above all other number.

Here is what I coded so far

```js
var arr = [3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3];
var input = 2;
var counter = 0;
for (var key in arr) {
  if (input > arr[key]) counter++;
}
console.log(counter);
```

I just came across this logic , but this does not give percentile between 0 to 100 , and also don't know it will be faster if I run with length of 1000 arrays.

When I see some python codes , its complex and  not simple like this.. Please some one guide me to calculate percentile in fastest way possible via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have it, you just have to calculate it by dividing `counter` by `arr.length` and then to format it as a percentage multiply by 100 and then use `toFixed` to truncate it to whichever precision you want.

```
const a = [3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3]
const i = 2
const c = 0
for (const v of a) {
  if (i > v) c++
}

const p = ((c / a.length) * 100).toFixed(2)
console.log(`${p}%`) // 16.67%
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , Why did I get 2 negative votes ?

Comment: Your question isn't specific and is more of a "solve my homework" for me style of question which there are a lot of here. Try to expand on your questions and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for collecting the matching numbers and then compute the percentage using the length of the initial array and the length of the filtered array.

```js
var arr = [3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 3];
var input = 2;
var percentage = 100 / arr.length * arr.filter(v => input > v).length;
console.log(Math.round(100 * percentage ) / 100);
```

The same result can be obtained with Array.reduce as follows:

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" id="pointspossible"/>
<input type="text" id="pointsgiven" />
<input type="text" id="pointsperc" />
```

```
$(function(){

$('#pointspossible').on('input', function() {
  calculate();
});
$('#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
 calculate();
});
function calculate(){
    var pPos = parseInt($('#pointspossible').val()); 
    var pEarned = parseInt($('#pointsgiven').val());
    var perc="";
    if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
        perc=" ";
       }else{
       perc = ((pEarned/pPos) * 100).toFixed(3);
       }

    $('#pointsperc').val(perc);
}
```

});